# How do I merge two lists within the cycle?

Tags: python, list, matrix, merge, gaussian

I have to create a list within a cycle which includes a Gauss function for z range(0,200)

```
def GetDepth():

    return float(a * 2.7 - (z - mu)**2 / (2 * sig**2))

for z in range(-1,200):

    k =[]
    z=z+1;
    for i in range(1):
        k.append(z);
        Gauss_list.append([z]);
        Gauss_list.append([GetDepth()]);
print(Gauss_list)
```

It returns something like:

```
[[0], [-1.0535849715692442], [1], [-0.8792864705363532], [2], [-0.7109879179039058], [3], [-0.5486893136719024], [4], [-0.39239065784034244]....
```

But what I need is:

```
 [[0, -1.0535849715692442], [1,-0.8792864705363532], [2,-0.7109879179039058], [3,-0.5486893136719024]....
```

That is for a Gauss plot. Maybe there is another option to make a plot without making 2-binary list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
    Gauss_list.append([z]);
    Gauss_list.append([GetDepth()]);
```

Use `append` at once:

```
    Gauss_list.append([z, GetDepth()])
```